# Read string from a file not working C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string str;
  ifstream file("file.txt");
  file >> str;
  cout << str;
  return 0;
}
```

I have `file.txt` in the same directory as `main.cpp`. I get no output from this, I've tried specifying full filepath to the file and still no result and tried it on few different machines too.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `file.txt` is supposed to be in the working directory.

Comment: what OS do you use? This regards the way how you need to write the full path

Comment: @MariusBancila I tried "~/cpp/filetest/file.txt" that should've been fine? If no, where should i put this file?

Comment: @user2407413, probably you need to check the "working directory" option in your IDE

Comment: @Ivan Thanks, I've found that and specified directory in options and it works. But how would I do that if I wasn't using IDE and just created cpp file in text editor and compiled using terminal?

Comment: @user2407413, I suppose, that by default in terminal working directory is the one where your executables are located

Comment: "if I wasn't using IDE and just created cpp file in text editor and compiled using terminal" - if the terminal shell you've move `mv` if necessary the C++ source code and `file.txt` into your current working directory (which you can see with `pwd` and change with `cd`), then compile ala `g++ -o myapp myapp.cc` then execute `.\myapp` - it will find `file.txt` in the same directory.

Comment: `~` is expanded by the shell, but you're not using the shell, so you need the **full** path

Comment: @Ivan, no, the working directory is whichever one you've changed to in the terminal, not the one where the executable is located. If I run `/bin/ls` the working directory is not `/bin`

Comment: @TonyD, that should be `./myapp`, backslashes in paths are for that toy OS

Comment: @JonathanWakely: very true... which I'm coding for now sadly... does my head in :-(.

Comment: You write that guy with "C:\\blah\\blah..\\cpp\\filetest\\file.txt" like that right because im sure that should work, im not sure about tilda but it can works too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're interested in is the [*current working directory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) for your program, i.e. where your text file is supposed to be if you don't qualify it with a full or relative path.

You can get it at runtime with [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) (linux) or [_getcwd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/sf98bd4y.aspx) (windows).

Edit: I agree with Andy, you should anyway check for errors when opening files. You could have caught this earlier (i.e. *file not found*), e.g.

<sub>*(pseudocode ahead for illustrative purposes)*</sub>

```
#include <unistd.h>

// Warning: linux-only, use #ifdefs and _getcwd for windows OS
std::string get_working_path() {
    char cwd[1024];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
        return std::string(cwd);
    else
        return std::string("");
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream file("file.txt"); 
    if (file >> str)
        std::cout << str;
    else {
        std::cout << "File not found in cwd: " << get_working_path();
        // abort
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To piggyback, OP *should* be checking for a successful file open. This would have hinted much sooner that there was an issue with the path: `ifstream file("file.txt"); if (file >> str) { cout << str;} else cout << "Bad path\n";`

Comment: People who ask iostreams question on stackoverflow **never** have error checking in their code. It's depressing. Their teachers should be hit with large sticks.

Comment: This is great. Few answers to these questions on SO provide code that _shows_ the OP what the current working directory is (and thus, what they're misunderstanding).

Comment: @JonathanWakely I have used file.is_open() to check first and then perform actions on a file, but I simplified the code for the sake of question. So no need to be worried so much, and I think my teachers shall be safe :)